# 80s sci-fi/fantasy cartoon where bread is somehow rolled up and used like a bomb

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have been trying to identify this for years with no success. I was born in the early 90s and watched this as a small child, most likely between the years 1996 and 2001.

What I remember: English language, but could have been dubbed. Western-style cartoon animation. It did not seem particularly dated at the time (at least to my eyes), so I would guess that it was produced sometime between the 1980s and when I viewed it, probably no earlier. I may have either watched it broadcast on cable (in the United States) or on a VHS tape. It may have been either a full animated movie, or a single episode of some series.

The setting seemed to be a mixture of sci-fi and fantasy. There were strong *Star Wars* vibes: I remember there being both a magical *or* technologically advanced sword-like weapon as well as an older mentor figure. I remember a lot of green -- possibly some scenes took place in a forest? As far as the plot, I remember almost nothing except for a scene where the 'good guys' are eating some kind of meal at what I believe to be the villain's lair/castle, when one of them rolls up some bread (or similar food) into a ball with his hands and somehow uses it to make a kind of bomb/smoke bomb that helps them escape. As I was very young, some of these details may be inaccurate.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nice description! If you want to add or change anything you can do so by [edit]ing your question. You may also want to take the [tour] to learn a bit about how the site works.

Comment: Did you watch this show in the US?

Comment: @JohnHunt Yes, sorry for leaving that out! Edited the question to add that detail.

Comment: I think I have incredibly vague memories of something similar, but I can't identify it. Did the person sprinkle something on the bread and add fuses to them? Maybe use it on barred windows?

Do you remember anything about the character who made the bombs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it was *Highlander: The Animated Series*.

[Season 1, episode 2](https://youtu.be/g3WknTQMgxg?t=451):

> Clyde: My brother's life is in danger and all you can do is make breadballs! Aren't you going to help him?
>
> Ramírez: Shhh, calm down. I need to concentrate.
>
> Clyde: What's that? [Ramirez sprinkles some kind of powder onto the bread???]
>
> Ramírez: You'll see.

Then he lights it up to blast their way out. Mystery solved.